# How to set video mode in .yaml file for camera_1394 and load .yaml file via launch parameter

Tags: ros, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using ROS Indigo with fire wire camera_1394 (flear2 from point grey which is supporting our target video mode)
launching with a launchfile (how to add the .yaml file as a parameter here?)

target video mode is 640x480_yuv422, we only get rgb8

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211000/how-to-set-video-mode-in-.yaml-file-for-camera_1394-and-load-.yaml-file-via-launch-parameter/) by [Team_TAPS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22733/team_taps/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-06-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-12**:
What is the web page of the ros driver for that camera?

**Comment by [Team_TAPS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22733/team_taps/) on 2015-06-17**:
not sure if you meant this but here is the drivers git: https://github.com/ros-drivers/camera1394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the parameters from http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394 7.1 could be set in a yaml that is loaded like `<rosparam command="load" file="$(find rosparam)/example.yaml" />` within a launch file that launches the camera1394 node (and put the rosparam load inside the private namespace of the camera node).  http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1